# Given two CXXRecordDecl for class A and B, is there an easy way to see if A is implicitly convertible to B?

Tags: c++, clang-ast-matchers

The X: Trying to write an internal clang tidy tool that finds an expression that contains two types (`A`, `B`) and then throws if `const A&` is implicitly convertible to `B`?

Given I can find two `CXXRecordDecl` for the classes, can I easily detect if `A` is implicitly convertible to `B`?

I've thought of walking over the constructors but that won't cover if B provides casting operators. I could walk over them both but I'm sure there are more cases that I'm missing here (like externally defined casting operators). Basically I want to detect if `std::is_convertible<const B&, A>::value` would return true, something every compiler has to do when validating a cast, but very difficult for a human to write...

Comment: by implicit, what do you mean?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Essentially, `std::is_convertible<const B&, A>::value` would return true.

Comment: It seems to me, that if you are concerned with other ways in which `A` could be converted to `B`, though operators, and such, you are going to have to make your own `is_convertible`, which looks into the class defs for those operators.

Comment: While that may be true that it isn't available in a way I can use today, every implementation of the compiler *has* to do this check in order to see if a implicit conversion is possible. Writing it from scratch correctly is probably super tricky cuz c++ is wack. It isn't just class defs, i'll also have to scan for stand alone operators as well, but only those available at the call site for the implicit conversion.

Comment: based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible I would say that you should check for inheritance (method isDerivedFrom of `CXXRecordDecl`), cast (using conversion_begin(), conversion_end() of `CXXRecordDecl`) and constructors (using ctor_begin(), conversion_end() of `CXXRecordDecl`). Don't you think it is sufficient ?

Comment: isDerivedFrom only works if the Derivation has an implicit copy constructor, I think? We'd also need to go find any casting operators that have the two types. Also have to be careful about value type vs rhr vs lhr.

Comment: was there ever a solution for this?